# Does the drive train of an EV affect the charging speed of the battery? Why?

Tags: batteries, battery-charging

In the latest tesla announcement they said:

> “Paired with the new more efficient drivetrain design, Model S and Model X are now capable of achieving 200 kW on V3 Superchargers and 145 kW on V2 Superchargers."

The Renault Zoe also appears to have a connection between motor and charging speeds:

> In June 2015, Renault announced the introduction of a new, smaller electric motor called the R240, manufactured at its Cléon engine plant.[28] The new motor has the same power and torque that the Q210 unit[3] with an extended NEDC cycle range of 240 km (150 mi).[3] However, **the Q210 would still be available as the R240 did not allow quick charging.** ~ [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Renault_Zoe#ZE20)

Why does the drivetrain impact charging speeds?!

Comment: Nowhere in the text does it state that the drivetrain impacts the charging speed. According to me drivetrain and charging are separate systems. They simply upgraded both individually.

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie Possibly, but it seems to me that a bidirectional motor control inverter and a battery charger have a lot of large expensive parts in common, I would not be shocked by a design that used the traction electronics as the on car part of the battery charging arrangements. Not saying Tesla did that, but it would not be a surprising design IMHO.

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie English is not the my first language and I know nothing about electrics but I added another example where it does sound like the motor affects the charging speed. I'd appreciate that you do not vote down something if you don't understand it. Otherwise please provide sources for your claim.

Comment: This isn't a valid question as it stands. Questions on how this or that commercial electronics do this or that based on tenuous claims from the suppliers are pretty much off-topic. Additionally, a motor called R240 is a MOTOR and not a battery/charge system so, why should a motor (called R240) disallow any charging high or low. Your 2nd quote just doesn't make sense.

Comment: It appears that the word "drivetrain" has been expanded from a mechanical term to cover everything in the electric machine and power electronics system that replaced the IC engine and mechanical drivetrain. The motor itself has nothing to do with charging except in the minds of the marketing people that write the type of material quoted. Voting to close as primarily opinion based.

Comment: @Andyaka I know the quotes don't make sense. Hence why I thought I'd ask in an experts group. Aparently everyone is more worried about downvoting than trying to clarify.

Comment: Might this be a better fit on the mechanics SE?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a great number of modules associated with a modern EV. I suggest you view some of the excellent [video series](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5gDILvW5yMg) produced by Professor John Kelly at Weber State. In the particular video I linked, he explains differences for the DC fast-charge compatible model of the Bolt.

If you follow the source for the Wikipedia article you linked (which you should **always** do),  it's a bit more clear they are talking about two different models of car.

As Mr. Cowie indicates "drive train" in current usage includes all those modules, and the battery, as well as the usual motor, gearbox, differential and so on.